# How to Make Bootstrap Top-Level Menu Items Clickable in Mobile View?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

More precisely...

Using Bootstrap, I have a nav menu with sub-menu items ([the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkdsleeper/Ye5Nq/)).

However, it's ...*a bit much*... in the Mobile viewport. Too many links.

I'd like to be able to accomplish two things:

1. Hide the sub-nav items, and...
2. Make the top-level items clickable (href resolve to a page)

I've been hunting around the bootstrap site and cannot find anything on this.

Is it possible using native Bootstrap?

If a script is needed, please provide a few *"pointers"*.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to be able to expand the sub-menu items on mobile? If so, it's probably impractical to make the top-level links into direct URLs.
Some "pointers" for that scenario (using jQuery, which is already integrated with Bootstrap plugins):

```
$('.nav .dropdown-menu').hide();  
$('.nav .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.nav .dropdown-menu').toggle();
});
```

Or, if you want to *only* display top-level links on mobile, you might store the link targets in a custom data- attribute and dynamically change the href values:

```
$('.nav .dropdown-menu').hide();
$('.nav .caret').hide();
$('.nav .dropdown-toggle').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('name'));
});
```

while adding a 'data-name' attribute to each link.

```
<a href="#" data-name="page.php">Page</a>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Nice! Thanks a bunch!  One question, is their already a hook in Bootstrap which captures the screen size (so I can run custom code) or do I need to write something? Thanks Again.

Comment: I haven't dissected the Bootstrap jQuery plugins, but I'd strongly recommend writing your own screen size hook regardless - that way when the Bootstrap core updates, you won't have to worry about adapting your code to keep up with theirs.